# What is wrong with my Laplace Transform?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I need to find the Laplace transform of sine(t), and it is proving rather difficult.  I integrate by parts, then integrate by parts again so that the original integral is on both sides of the equation, then I get it wrong.

$ f\left(x\right) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       \sin t & : 0 \leq t \le \pi\\
       0 & : t > 1
     \end{array}
   \right.\\$

Because the Laplace Transform of 0 is 0, I concern myself with:
$$\int{e^{-st}\sin{t}\space \mathrm{dt}}$$ and proceed with integration by parts.  I have $u=\sin{t}$,$du=\cos{t}$,$dv=e^{-st}$ and last but not least $dv=\frac{e^{-st}}{s}$.  This yields the equation:

$$\int{e^{-st}\sin{t}\space \mathrm{dt}}=\frac{1}{s}\left(-\sin{t}e^{-st}+\int{e^{-st}\cos{t}\space \mathrm{dt}}\right)$$ and so I begin to solve the Laplace transform of cosine.

For this, I use $u=\cos{t}$,$du=-\sin{t}$,$dv=e^{-st}$,$v=\frac{e^{-st}}{s}$.  This yields the equation:
$$\int{e^{-st}\cos{t}\space \mathrm{dt}}=\frac{-\cos{t}e^{-st}}{s}-\frac{1}{s}\int{e^{-st}\sin{t}\space \mathrm{dt}}$$.

Now, we obviously use this solution to replace the prior integral that we just solved, 
 $$\int{e^{-st}\sin{t}\space \mathrm{dt}}=-\frac{\sin{t}e^{-st}}{s}+\frac{1}{s}\left( \frac{-\cos{t}e^{-st}}{s}-\frac{1}{s}\int{e^{-st}\sin{t}\space \mathrm{dt}})\right)$$

Which simplifies to:
$$(1+s^2)\int{e^{-st}\sin{t}\space \mathrm{dt}}=\frac{-\sin{t}e^{-st}}{s}+\frac{-\cos{t}e^{-st}}{s^2}$$.

Now let us suppose the bounds of our equation are $0$ and $\pi$.  This leads our terms to be as such: 
$$\left[\frac{-\cos{t}e^{-st}}{s^2}\right]^{\pi}_0=\frac{e^{-\pi s}}{s^2+1}\frac{1}{s^2}$$.

The book gives the answer as merely $$\frac{e^{-\pi s}}{s^2+1}$$.  How do I get rid of my extraneous $\frac{1}{s^2}$?

Comment: $1+\frac1{s^2}=\frac{s^2+1}{s^2}$ shouls be the coefficient in front of the integral on the left side, where you say "Which simplifies to:" This is a simple algebra mistake, not calculus. Correct as $\frac{(1+s^2)}{s^2}\int{e^{-st}\sin{t}\space \mathrm{dt}}=\frac{-\sin{t}e^{-st}}{s}+\frac{-\cos{t}e^{-st}}{s^2}$. Later the $s^2$ in the denominator on the left side will cancel with the $s^2$ in the denominator on the right side.